# Flask logging handler information

Tags: python, flask, logging, handler

I have two logging handlers configured in my flask app. How to get the handler name which is in use by the app so according to that I will handle the logging.

Answer (score 0):

`logging.basicConfig(filename=’<yourfilename>.log‘, level=logging.DEBUG, format=’%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s’)`

in this

`%(asctime)s—A timestamp as a string.`
`%(levelname)s—The logging level as a string.`
`%(threadName)s—The thread name as a string.`
`%(message)s’—The log message.`

-->>    `%(name)s—The logger name as a string.`

[here](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-with-flask-logging/) is the reference for the same

Comment: The reference link (https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-with-flask-logging/) appears to have died.